# Rails: Javascript e.preventDefault(); not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have been trying to solve this for quite some time now, but without any luck thus far. So any help would be very much appreciated!

I have two search `form_tags` inside dynamics tabs:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="prodTabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#search">Search</a></li>
    <li><a href="#other"  data-toggle="tab">Other</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="nearby">
      <%= render 'pages/search' %>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane" id="other">
      <%= render 'pages/search_other' %>
    </div>

<script>
$('#tabs').on('click','.tablink,#prodTabs a',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr("data-url");

    if (typeof url !== "undefined") {
        var pane = $(this), href = this.hash;

        // ajax load from data-url
        $(href).load(url,function(result){
            pane.tab('show');
        });
    } else {
        $(this).tab('show');
    }
});
</script>
```

'pages/search' form partial:

```
<div id="form">
<%= form_tag url_for(:controller => 'pages', :action => 'search'), :method => "get" do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], autofocus: true, placeholder: "Enter keyword to search" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, :style => "display: none;" %>
  <%end%>
  </div>
```

'pages/search_other' form partial:

```
<div id="other">
<%= form_tag url_for(:controller => 'pages', :action => 'search_other'), method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search_other, params[:search_other], autofocus: true, placeholder: "Enter keyword to search" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :style => "display: none;"  %>
  <%end%>
</div>
```

As you can see I have two different actions inside the controller, along with two different routes for each search form. And everything works perfectly thus far!!!

But if I implement the following only for the `'pages/search' form partial`... the geolocation popup appears but after I click allow it `GETS` the `'pages/search_other' form partial` and after that redirects me to the results of that search, which is weird and of course wrong. I have no clue why this is happening though!

My goal here is for the geolocation popup to appear once I submit the `'pages/search' form partial` and after I hit allow it will redirect me to the results of that search form:

```
<script>
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    getGeoLocation();

});
</script>
```

search.js

```
function getGeoLocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setGeoCookie);
}


function setGeoCookie(position) {
    var cookie_val = position.coords.latitude + "|" + position.coords.longitude;
    document.cookie = "lat_lng=" + escape(cookie_val);
    $('form').submit();
}
```

Comment: try to put console. with `$('#form').submit(function(e) {console.log("IN form", e)});`  ,let me know what do you get after submit the form

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Vishal... do u mean like this? `$('#form').submit(function(e) {
        console.log("IN form", e)
        e.preventDefault();
        getGeoLocation();

    });`

Comment: first of all check whether the form submits correctly, than after you can move to your function. currently comment the other function

Comment: Ok, with only this `$('#form').submit(function(e) {console.log("IN form", e)});` it does submit the correct form and redirects correctly!!! with no errors in console or web browser inspector!

Comment: do you get the value of `e` ?

Comment: Where should I check?

Comment: Please check it in your web console. do you know where is web console ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using safari, so web inspector and after that `console` is returning nothing! Have no values in there!

Comment: So it is not going to your click event try this one `$(document).on("submit" ,"#form" (function(e) { console.log("In form submit event",e) });`  please let me know the output

Comment: The code you just provided seems to be wrong! Rubymine underlines it in red!

Comment: and it returns an error inside the inpsector `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';'. Expected ')' to end an argument list.`

Comment: Ohh it was syntax error , please try this `$(document).on("submit" ,"#form", function(e) { console.log("In form submit event",e) });`

Comment: Again, it returns nothing inside the console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163859/discussion-between-vishal-and-dev).